# What should i do when rabbitmq blocking event is triggered?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqplib

I am creating a rabbitmq connection while starting my nodejs app and i created a doPublish function which is using channels internally ( created from that connection ) for publishing.If rabbitmq publish call returns true then everything is fine but when it is returning false then i am storing that publishing data in a file as a backup.
Now when rabbitmq fires an blocked event then publish call will not return anything( my guess).
So how should i handle this block event? I have a continuous call of doPublish function for each client request.